# Trying to link an icon to a window that displays my email and functions so people can contact me through my site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sass

so i'm trying to link this mail icon to a screen that opens like a small mail pop up so people can send me an email through my site with the provided email (mine of course)

```
<div class="container-icons">
   <i class="icon icon-envelop"></i>
   <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
   <i class="icon icon-instagram"></i>
   <i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i>
</div>
```

Here is the link to a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/axelnijsten/pen/jOObwbB).

Comment: You're trying to? I don't see anything in that code that's an attempt to link the icon to an email.

Comment: Your codepen has no content. Also, please read how to ask a question on stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i updated the codepen link so it should be correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to have the user click an icon and open their default email program (outlook, apple mail, etc). This can be achieved by wrapping the mail icon in an anchor tag. Like so:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top"> 
     <i class="icon icon-envelop"></i>
</a>
```

When the user clicks it, their default email program on their machine will open with the email address and subject line already populated. For more information on `mailto`'s read [this post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/).

Comment: thank you i will try to implement this and keep you posted